# Error : UrlHelper.Link must not return null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating REST Services. Here I want to create a Post service. Data is inserted into a database, but in response I got this error

> UrlHelper.Link must not return null..

My Code

```
  [HttpPost]
       [Route("api/CourseRegistrations")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CourseRegistration))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCourseRegistration(CourseRegistration         courseRegistration)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.CourseRegistrations.Add(courseRegistration);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = courseRegistration.course_id }, courseRegistration);
    }
```

Comment: I am dubious the code you provided is relevant.  Would you mind showing a few lines of your stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you're using default setting inside `WebApiConfig` class in `App_Start` folder like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Thus it is necessary to provide controller name parameter in `CreatedAtRoute` method, as in example below:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { controller = "ApiControllerName", id = courseRegistration.course_id }, courseRegistration);
```

However, since `RouteAttribute` is present, it indicates that attribute routing is enabled, then you should provide route name for GET route with proper parameter name and then set POST route as shown in example below:

```
// GET method
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/CourseRegistrations/{id}", Name = "GetCourseRegistrationById")]
[ResponseType(typeof(CourseRegistration))]
public IHttpActionResult GetCourseRegistration(int id)
{
    // do something
}

// POST method
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/CourseRegistrations")]
public IHttpActionResult PostCourseRegistration(CourseRegistration courseRegistration)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.CourseRegistrations.Add(courseRegistration);
    db.SaveChanges();

    // replace 'DefaultApi' with route name for redirect to GET method
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetCourseRegistrationById", new { id = courseRegistration.course_id }, courseRegistration);
}
```

**Note:**

1) The parameter name contained inside `CreatedAtRoute` must match with target parameter name used in action method, otherwise the [`UrlHelper.Link()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944702(v%3Dvs.118)) method will return null.

2) The route name in `RouteAttribute` should be different from action method name to avoid confusion.

Reference:

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2: Route Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-names)

Related issue:

[Attribute Routing and CreatedAtRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117882/attribute-routing-and-createdatroute)