# CreatedAtRoute generates an exception : "No route matches the supplied values."

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ef-core-2.2

Using my Post functions to create rows in tables generates a 500 response AND writes the data.
The response body is a html, and the error seems to be the following:

```
<h1>An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.</h1>
            <div class="titleerror">InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.</div>
                <p class="location">Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)</p>
```

Apparently, my error occurs at my `CreatedAtRoute` response.

I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what post does and how links should get generated for the new entries in tables.

I am using swagger to call my endpoints.

I tried reading up on how to generate links, but the concepts drown me.
I tried messing around with the `CreatedAtRoute` response but I can't seem to figure out the proper parameters I need to send, or what exactly it does.

Controller:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Location),200)]
        [HttpGet("locations/{locationId}", Name = "LocationById")]
        public IActionResult GetLocation(int locationId)
```

```
[HttpPost("locations")]
        public IActionResult CreateLocation([FromBody] CreateLocationRequest createLocationRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                if (createLocationRequest == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return CreatedAtRoute("LocationById",_repository.Location.CreateLocation(createLocationRequest),createLocationRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, e.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

Repository:

```
public int CreateCompany(string name, int countryId, int? parentId)//string name, int countryId, int? parentId
        {
            Company company = new Company()
            {
                CountryId = countryId,
                Name = name,
                ParentId = parentId
            };
            _context.Companies.Add(company);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return company.Id;
        }
```

Startup route config:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

I need a proper route towards my newly created table entries. Any suggestions on how to obtain this would be extremely appreciated.

After reading a bit about CreatedAtRoute, I tried tweaking my functions to try and see if passing the entity itself instead of the model when calling `CreatedAtRoute` would do anything to help my cause. It did not.

New methods:
Repository:

```
public LocationReturns CreateLocation(CreateLocationRequest createLocationRequest)
        {
            if (_context.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == createLocationRequest.CompanyId) != null)
            {
                LocationReturns locationReturns=new LocationReturns();
                Location location = new Location()
                {
                    Address = createLocationRequest.Address,
                    AllowedAsSource = createLocationRequest.AllowedAsSource,
                    City = createLocationRequest.City,
                    CompanyId = createLocationRequest.CompanyId,
                    Name = createLocationRequest.Name,
                    Picture = createLocationRequest.Picture,
                    PostCode = createLocationRequest.Postcode,
                    Region = createLocationRequest.Region
                };
                _context.Locations.Add(location);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                locationReturns.id = location.Id;
                locationReturns.loc = location;
                return locationReturns;
            }
            LocationReturns loc = new LocationReturns();
            return loc;
        }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("locations")]
        public IActionResult CreateLocation([FromBody] CreateLocationRequest createLocationRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                if (createLocationRequest == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                LocationRepository.LocationReturns locationReturns=new LocationRepository.LocationReturns();
                locationReturns = _repository.Location.CreateLocation(createLocationRequest);

                return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi",new {id=locationReturns.id}, locationReturns.loc);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, e.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

Where LocationReturns is a struct.

Comment: Seeing the error message we can conclude that your code is never reached. Which URL are you using to call the API? And how do you configure the routes in `Startup`?

Comment: `"api/admin/locations"` is how I call this. Which part of the code is never reached? Coz like, as I was saying, calling this endpoint actually writes new rows.

Comment: ` No route matches the supplied values` suggests that it doesn't know where to route the call. I don't see the `api/admin` part in your route configuration. Have you used a debugger to step through the code and see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CreatedAtRoute routing to different controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417559/createdatroute-routing-to-different-controller)

Comment: On closer inspection it's your use of `CreatedAtRoute` - see the duplication

Comment: I am invoking the route attribute at the start of the class, which is called AdminController. `[Route("api/[controller]")]` `[ApiController]`. It's why you don't see the `api/admin` part. It gets concatenated. I don't really know how to use a debugger.

Comment: You should really read up on using a debugger. It would have told you which line is causing the problem and you could have investigated why and read the state of the program at that time.

Comment: I mentioned in the question body that the issue seems to be at the `CreatedAtRoute` call. I'd appreciate a good source that explains how to properly use a debugger in vs when creating WEB APIs.

Comment: All you need to do is place a breakpoint and launch the program using the debugger in visual studio (any version including code) - when you call the API it will stop at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous object generated inside the `CreateAtRoute()` had to have an int prop with the same name as the parameter declared in the route. Ex:
`[HttpGet("/locations/{locationId}, Name="LocationCreated"`
requires
`CreatedAtRoute("LocationCreated", new {locationId=id}, locationObject);`
instead of `CreatedAtRoute("LocationCreated", new {id=_id}, locationObject);`