# CreatedAction does not accept endpoint action name from another controller

Tags: c#, .net-5

I'm experimenting with a different REST API design. I created a new .Net 5 app with one model and two controllers

```
public sealed record Todo(string Title, string OwnedBy, bool IsDone = false);

public sealed class TodoQueriesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("my-todo-by-title/{title}")]
    [ActionName(nameof(GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle))]
    public ActionResult<Todo> GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle([FromRoute] string title)
    {
        string authenticatedUsername = "foo";
        
        return Ok(new Todo(title, authenticatedUsername));
    }
}

public sealed class TodoCommandsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("assign-todo-to-me")]
    public ActionResult<Todo> AssignTodoToAuthenticatedUser([FromBody] string title)
    {
        string authenticatedUsername = "foo";
        
        return CreatedAtAction("???", new { title }, new Todo(title, authenticatedUsername));
    }
}
```

Currently I don't know what to pass in as an action name for the `CreatedAtAction` (to replace `"???"`)

I tried

- `nameof(TodoQueriesController.GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle)`
- `"GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle"`
- `"my-todo-by-title"`
- `$"my-todo-by-title/{title}"`

but unfortunately I always got a 500 with

> System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.

How can I reference the endpoint action from another controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CreatedAtAction overload with the controllerName parameter.

```
CreatedAtActionResult CreatedAtAction (string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object value)
```

Check out the Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: You mean like so? `CreatedAtAction(nameof(TodoQueriesController.GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle), nameof(TodoQueriesController), new { title }, new Todo(title, authenticatedUsername));` That didn't work neither

Comment: I just now realize that you are using the [FromRoute] attribute. This doesn't work with CreatedAtAction because there is no way to pass the title from route. I think you will need to use CreatedAtRoute in this case and append the title value to the route string like so:
CreatedAtRoute(nameof(TodoQueriesController.GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle) + title, nameof(TodoQueriesController), new Todo(title, authenticatedUsername));

Comment: sorry, this method provides no overload for the controller name. I also tried `CreatedAtRoute(nameof(TodoQueriesController.GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle), new Todo(title, authenticatedUsername));` and `CreatedAtRoute(nameof(TodoQueriesController.GetTodoFromAuthenticatedUserByTitle) + title, new Todo(title, authenticatedUsername));`

Comment: you can specify the controller in the route parameters. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417559/createdatroute-routing-to-different-controller)